# Wrap code in a custom closure during build process

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

I'd like to wrap my code in a custom type of Closure during build process with Grunt (and uglify). This manipulation must keep the sourceMap working.

My use case is to wrap all my code inside a `try/catch` block to allow logging of the errors in production - without losing access to the stacktrace (unlike `window.onerror`). I'd probably use Raven-js 1.0 to work this out.

Anyone know how I could manage this easily?

*If you just have tips that might bring a full answer, that'll be accepted too*

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I've found a grunt plugin ([grunt-wrap](https://github.com/chrissrogers/grunt-wrap)) who does exactly this:

```
  wrap: {
    modules: {
      src: ['assets/*.js'],
      dest: 'dist/',
      wrapper: ['try {', '} catch(e) { Raven.captureException(e); }']
    }
  }
```

If you're interested in `raven-js`. I've been with the `try/catch` over `Raven.context` as this won't create a new global closure around the code.